# How to keep inventory on polycraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Any way to keep the inventory and the items without losing them once we die and respawn? There is no option for LAN and the cheats doesn't work as I am in a polycraft mod server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current options are:

- Set the gamerule `keepInventory` to true. This requires admin permissions.
- Talk to an admin of the server so they can set `keepInventory` to true.
- Start your own Polycraft server so you're an admin, and set `keepInventory` to true.

Outside of that, you'll be stuck with dropping your inventory if you die.